# Shooting a projectile at moving objects in game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making an iOS game where the hero is at the very left of the screen (landscape mode) and she shoots at monsters coming from the right side. Now I am following this tutorial because I am a beginner at iOS games: https://www.raywenderlich.com/71-spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

The issue I am having is that the code in the tutorial is from 2013. That affects the positions of the CGPoints on the Scene (because the center now is the middle as opposed to the left edge) but also there may already be functions that make it easier. For example, in the tutorial they declare

```
func +(left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}

func -(left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: left.x - right.x, y: left.y - right.y)
}

func *(point: CGPoint, scalar: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: point.x * scalar, y: point.y * scalar)
}

func /(point: CGPoint, scalar: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
  return CGPoint(x: point.x / scalar, y: point.y / scalar)
}

#if !(arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64))
  func sqrt(a: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(sqrtf(Float(a)))
  }
#endif

extension CGPoint {
  func length() -> CGFloat {
    return sqrt(x*x + y*y)
  }

  func normalized() -> CGPoint {
    return self / length()
  }
}
```

Only to be able to count the offset between two points and set the location of where the projectile should go:

```
let offset = touchLocation - projectile.position
let direction = offset.normalized()
```

Is there an updated version of code for the above code and please, if there are any other tutorials for beginners that implement a shooting projectile functionality, link them in the answers. Thank you!

Comment: The code looks ok to me, are you having a specific problem with it? asking for tutorials or other off-site resources is off-topic.

Comment: No I am asking if it is outdated or if there are built in functions now that help do the same tasks. It's from 2013 and a lot has changes in xcode since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't already, you can import all of the SpriteKit helper functions via the GitHub repo instead of reproducing them yourself. They still work, I've used them recently myself.

https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils/tree/master/SKTUtils

Answer (score 1):

The code block you included utilizes **[Operator Functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID42)**. `CGPoint` does not have arithmetic operators.

Definition of arithmetic operators as stated in [Swift Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID42):

> ***Arithmetic Operators*** is a binary operator because it operates on two targets and is said to be **infix** because it appears in between those two targets.

To better understand let's figure out what **CGPoint** is.

### CGPoint

According to [Swift Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpoint), CGPoint is:

> A structure that contains a point in a two-dimensional coordinate
>   system.

The two-dimensions are **x** and **y**. There are three init methods for initializing a CGPoint.

```
init(x: Double, y: Double)
init(x: Int, y: Int)
init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)
```

As you can see, `x` and `y` can be of type `Double`, `Int`, or `CGFloat`. Those data types have arithmetic operators.

Although `CGPoint` does not have built-in arithmetic operators, you can create them and hence the code block you have suffice that.